# JMS transacted session: Commit / rollback for specific message

Tags: session, jms, commit, rollback

I use 1 session, 1 asynchronous MessageListener to receive messages and processing each message in thread. After thread done, session commit or rollback will be used to decide message can be redelivered or not. But I really concern about commit/rollback statement could have any affect to those messages which are processing in threads. For example

```
1 session
1 msg listener

---TIME---->
[MSG1: receive] --------------- processing -----------------> [MSG1: rollback]
               [MSG2: receive] --------------> [MSG2: commit]


- At the time MSG2 commit, may be MSG1 also be committed?
If it is right, can I execute commit/rollback for specific MSG only?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not shared any code but I will try to answer.

First, This doesn't seem a good strategy,

> session commit or rollback will be used to decide message can be
>   redelivered or not

I think, you should use message acknowledgement mode to decide for re delivery. Set appropriate acknowledgement mode in messages as per your need.

Secondly, You seem to be mixing presence of threads with JMS `Session` being **transacted** or not. To `commit` or `rollback` a single JMS message, your session need to be transacted for a single JMS message.

[Transacted Session](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Connection.html#createSession-boolean-int-)

so I guess, your `commit` or `rollback` for one message affects other message or not doesn't depend on your threads but how you defined a transaction and how many messages constituted a transaction ( i.e. how a transaction is scoped ).

Its a `Session` `commit` and `rollback` not `Message` `commit` or `rollback`.

Hope it helps !!